# How to report suspicious seller on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

How to report a suspicious seller on Amazon? The top three sellers below have no feedback 'just launched' and strange names that could have been randomly generated by a computer. Their prices are a fraction of the market price. I'm sceptical they are legit.

1. KISHWA JENKINS *Just Launched*
2. ARCHIE BELDIN| *Just Launched*
3. cuinzqyowr *Just Launched*

Is there any way to inform Amazon of my suspicions about these sellers? I want to protect other shoppers. I know how to report a problem with an order, but I haven't made an order and don't intend to.

If Amazon are concerned about protecting customers against scams, I think they show have a 'report seller' or 'report listing' button on this page *before they make an order*. Prevention is better than cure.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B0162YQHJA/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new

[image]

---

What's the scam here? Do they ship counterfeit or inferior goods (ie. a smaller memory chip), or do they simply take customers' money and run?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the [general contact form](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/contact-us/general-questions.html?). This is behind your login.

Select *An order I placed*. Assuming that you do not have an order with that merchant, click *Choose a different order*, then on the right click *Cannot find my order* to proceed:

[image]

In the dropdowns that appear, there are no specific choices for you. Choose *Other order issues* and *Something else*. If you want you can then go into chat.

---

[This page](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/reports/infringement) is specifically for copyright infringement by a seller:

> This form is intended for use by rights owners and their agents to notify Amazon of alleged infringements such as copyright and trademark concerns. If you are not a rights owner or their agent, Amazon will not be able to process complaints submitted through this form.